# How to sound like Yoda

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, recording, software

I'm not too sure if this is the proper category of this site to ask this question but... There's a chance I may make a Star Wars fan film at some point in the future. If I want to use the script I'm currently working on, I need to figure out how to make my voice sound like Yoda's. Is there any way for me to do this in the software I use (Mixcraft 5)?

Comment: Yoda's voice is not created by using effects. It was just Frank Oz doing a Yoda voice. There are yoda voice effects out there - just google them - but your best bet is to learn how to impersonate his voice.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of pinch your throat near your sinuses. I don't think you can do this with any amount of success with software. You could ENHANCE it with some EQ, depending on what the person you're recording sounds like.